# wizard form chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, wizard

Over the last days I have been trying to implement a wizard form by using jquery on chrome extension, but it seems to impossible (for me). I have tried to adapt some libraries such as

http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyWizard/

and

http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/

Can any one tell me how can I implement a wizard form on chrome extension? or some examples please.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the libraries you cited, but here's a very easy approach:

```
<div id="one">Panel 1 form content<button id="button_one">Next</button></div>
<div id="two">Panel 2 form content<button id="button_two">Next</button></div>
<div id="three">Panel 3 form content<button id="button_three">Next</button></div>
```

Start out by hiding all but the first div. Set up button_one's click handler to hide div one and show div two, and so on. The last panel might have a "Done" button that submits all the content, or whatever it is you wanted to do. Once you have this working, you can start getting fancy with transitions, tab behavior, and nicer CSS.

By the way, you should consider prototyping on a regular web page first before trying a Chrome extension. "On a Chrome extension" is very broad and doesn't really mean much on its own; it could be a popup, it could be designed to enhance specific web pages, it could be an overlay on any web page. We don't know from your question, and that's why it's good to have something very simple working on a regular web page that you can then adapt to your extension. The simple approach outlined here should be a good foundation for your project.